# How to use RowsPerPage in the REST API

Tags: search, sharepoint-rest-api, api

Whenever I send a request with `RowsPerPage` set, either via GET or POST, more rows than the `RowsPerPage` value are returned. `RowLimit` works though.

`/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&rowsperpage=1`

Why doesn't rowsperpage limit the amount of items returned? Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of `RowsPerPage`?

I'm on SP2013 on prem.